# HTTP request to VM

Tags: http, tcp

I have a jetty server running under port 8080 on VM. VM in its turn runs on remote server under port 10000. Is it legit to address it as http://someremote.org:10000:8080/request? Or should I use SSH somehow?

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is called ssh tunneling. You make a tunnel from your port to remote's machine port like that:

```
ssh -p 10000 -L 18080:localhost:8080 user@remote.host.org
```

18080 here is port, that you use on your local machine in order to get to remote's 8080 port.